# OpenWRT - Guest Wi-Fi on bridged client

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, openwrt, wireless-bridge

I have a spare WRT160NL which I configured as bridged client, mainly following [this guide](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/relayclient). 
Main Routers IP is 192.168.178.1 which also connects to the internet. WRT's IP is 192.168.178.2, this device is connected to the main router via wi-fi in client mode. The same SSID is then broadcasted in AP mode ("Mode: Master") and DHCP on the WRT is disabled. A bridge interface connects the "wireless wan" and the wireless net on the WRT.

### Problem

Now I would like to configure a guest wi-fi but can't seem to get it working.
I'm following [this guide](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/guest-wlan-webinterface). The new guest net is broadcasted and I can connect to it and also get an IP with DHCP. In a first step I tried to ping WRT's interface address of this net which is 192.168.3.1. This fails and I can't figure out why. Before trying anything else, tweaking firewall settings and so on I should be able to ping the routers IP from inside the subnet, shouldn't I?
Since I have a bridge interface ("stabridge") I added the guest interface to the bridge interface which also did not work.

### Config files

/etc/config/network

```
config interface 'loopback'
    option ifname 'lo'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
    option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config interface 'lan'
    option ifname 'eth0'
    option force_link '1'
    option type 'bridge'
    option proto 'static'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option gateway '192.168.178.1'
    option dns '192.168.178.1'
    option delegate '0'
    option ipaddr '192.168.178.3'

config interface 'wwan'
    option proto 'static'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option gateway '192.168.178.1'
    option delegate '0'
    option ipaddr '192.168.178.2'

config interface 'stabridge'
    option proto 'relay'
    option ipaddr '192.168.178.2'
    option delegate '0'
    list network 'guest'
    list network 'lan'
    list network 'wwan'

config interface 'guest'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '192.168.3.1'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option delegate '0'
```

/etc/config/wireless

```
config wifi-device 'radio0'
    option type 'mac80211'
    option hwmode '11g'
    option path 'platform/ath9k'
    option htmode 'HT20'
    option disabled '0'
    option channel '4'
    option txpower '21'
    option country 'US'

config wifi-iface
    option network 'wwan'
    option ssid 'wi-fi'
    option encryption 'psk2'
    option device 'radio0'
    option mode 'sta'
    option bssid '24:65:11:XX:XX:XX'
    option key 'wifipassword'

config wifi-iface
    option device 'radio0'
    option mode 'ap'
    option ssid 'wi-fi'
    option network 'lan'
    option encryption 'psk2'
    option key 'wifipassword'

config wifi-iface
    option device 'radio0'
    option mode 'ap'
    option network 'guest'
    option ssid 'wifi_guest'
    option encryption 'psk2'
    option key 'wifiguestpassword'
```

/etc/config/firewall

```
config defaults
    option syn_flood '1'
    option input 'ACCEPT'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option forward 'REJECT'

config zone
    option name 'lan'
    option input 'ACCEPT'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option forward 'ACCEPT'
    option network 'lan wwan'

config zone
    option name 'wan'
    option input 'REJECT'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option forward 'REJECT'
    option masq '1'
    option mtu_fix '1'
    option network 'wan wan6 wireless_open'

config forwarding
    option src 'lan'
    option dest 'wan'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-DHCP-Renew'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'udp'
    option dest_port '68'
    option target 'ACCEPT'
    option family 'ipv4'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-Ping'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'icmp'
    option icmp_type 'echo-request'
    option family 'ipv4'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-IGMP'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'igmp'
    option family 'ipv4'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-DHCPv6'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'udp'
    option src_ip 'fe80::/10'
    option src_port '547'
    option dest_ip 'fe80::/10'
    option dest_port '546'
    option family 'ipv6'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-MLD'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'icmp'
    option src_ip 'fe80::/10'
    list icmp_type '130/0'
    list icmp_type '131/0'
    list icmp_type '132/0'
    list icmp_type '143/0'
    option family 'ipv6'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-ICMPv6-Input'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'icmp'
    list icmp_type 'echo-request'
    list icmp_type 'echo-reply'
    list icmp_type 'destination-unreachable'
    list icmp_type 'packet-too-big'
    list icmp_type 'time-exceeded'
    list icmp_type 'bad-header'
    list icmp_type 'unknown-header-type'
    list icmp_type 'router-solicitation'
    list icmp_type 'neighbour-solicitation'
    list icmp_type 'router-advertisement'
    list icmp_type 'neighbour-advertisement'
    option limit '1000/sec'
    option family 'ipv6'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option name 'Allow-ICMPv6-Forward'
    option src 'wan'
    option dest '*'
    option proto 'icmp'
    list icmp_type 'echo-request'
    list icmp_type 'echo-reply'
    list icmp_type 'destination-unreachable'
    list icmp_type 'packet-too-big'
    list icmp_type 'time-exceeded'
    list icmp_type 'bad-header'
    list icmp_type 'unknown-header-type'
    option limit '1000/sec'
    option family 'ipv6'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config include
    option path '/etc/firewall.user'

config rule
    option src 'wan'
    option dest 'lan'
    option proto 'esp'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config rule
    option src 'wan'
    option dest 'lan'
    option dest_port '500'
    option proto 'udp'
    option target 'ACCEPT'

config zone
    option name 'guest'
    option input 'ACCEPT'
    option forward 'REJECT'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option network 'guest'

config forwarding
    option dest 'wan'
    option src 'guest'

config rule
    option target 'ACCEPT'
    option src 'guest'
    option proto 'tcp udp'
    option dest_port '53'
    option name 'Guest DNS'

config rule
    option enabled '1'
    option target 'ACCEPT'
    option src 'guest'
    option proto 'udp'
    option dest_port '67-68'
    option name 'Guest DHCP'
```

Bonus Points: I tried to configure the exact [same setup with DD-WRT](https://superuser.com/questions/970705/dd-wrts-repeater-bridge-mode-and-additional-virtual-interfaces-with-own-dhcp-ran) which also failed, I also could not ping the gateway from inside the guest net. Am I hitting some hardware limitation here?

What steps am I missing to configure the guest net to use "wwan" for connecting to the internet?
Thanks for looking!

[image: config]

Firewall settings:
[image: Firewall]

[image: Stabridge]

Removed guest net from bridge if, still can't ping guest gateway from inside guest net.

```
root@OpenWrt:~# ifconfig 
br-lan    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr BE:0F:EC:XX:XX:XX  
          inet addr:192.168.178.3  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::bc0f:ecff:fe6f:f226/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6944791 errors:0 dropped:4991 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11086842 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:581010664 (554.0 MiB)  TX bytes:15224175749 (14.1 GiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr BE:0F:EC:XX:XX:XX  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:291345 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:18850062 (17.9 MiB)
          Interrupt:4 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:149 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:149 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:10372 (10.1 KiB)  TX bytes:10372 (10.1 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:03:7F:XX:XX:XX  
          inet addr:192.168.178.2  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::203:7fff:fec0:7cfa/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10984215 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7134194 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2342342874 (2.1 GiB)  TX bytes:830422933 (791.9 MiB)

wlan0-1   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:03:7F:XX:XX:XX  
          inet6 addr: fe80::3:7fff:fec0:7cfa/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6989301 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11120218 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:714322711 (681.2 MiB)  TX bytes:2590755125 (2.4 GiB)

wlan0-2   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:03:7F:XX:XX:XX  
          inet addr:192.168.3.1  Bcast:192.168.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::403:7fff:fec0:7cfa/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:955 errors:0 dropped:6 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:270 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:90423 (88.3 KiB)  TX bytes:47057 (45.9 KiB)

root@OpenWrt:~# ifdown br-lan
Interface br-lan not found
root@OpenWrt:~# ifdown eth0
Interface eth0 not found
root@OpenWrt:~# ifdown wlan0
Interface wlan0 not found
root@OpenWrt:~# ifdown wlan0-1
Interface wlan0-1 not found
root@OpenWrt:~# ifdown wlan0-2
Interface wlan0-2 not found
```

Comment: Can you clarify, is the normal AP working and guest not, or neither?

Comment: AP is working fine. Bridged client mode works. Guest net is working to the point that I can connect and receive an IP address.

Comment: Guessing here but I believe you need a config a forward, also your main should be running two DHCP pools according to their docs.

Comment: I added a picture to clear things up a bit. The main router is also able to provide a guest net but the WRT only has one radio device so I am not able to connect to both (main and guest) nets in client mode at the same time. So I want a guest net provided by WRT with a separated subnet but using 192.168.178.1 as gateway to the internet.

Comment: Oh I've just realized. You're trying to pass the guest WLAN through the primary WLAN, its not a secondary link. I think you'll need to implement VLANs to work, traditional "guest networking" cant handle that.

Comment: Mhh, also on the main router? I don't think this device is able to handle VLANs. Can't I just masquerade the guest subnet or work with static routes or something?

Comment: Really this is the setup that VLANs exist for. I tried something similar with guest networks before and ended up in a situation where only VLAN tags could make it work.

Comment: I'm with you when it comes to guest LANs. All I need here is a virtual wi-fi interface not bridged to the private wi-fi but configured to use the main gateway IP to connect to the internet. Also I can not ping 192.168.3.1 when connected to the guest wlan, this should work out of the box with nothing else configured.

Comment: According to the [OpenWRT Wiki](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/linksys/wrt160nl) VLans are supported, although if you scroll to near the bottom of the page it seems they do have a few issues!

Comment: VLANs are completely irrelevant and nothing to do with wireless.

Comment: You have either mispasted your /etc/config/network or the file itself is broken - the section for the guest network is cut off prematurely and incomplete.

Comment: D'Oh. Edited this...

Comment: What IP addresses are your clients on the guest network getting? First problem I can see is that 'guest' is part of the stabridge, and it shouldn't be. They probably can't ping 192.168.3.1 because they're getting relayed DHCP leases from the 192.168.178.x range. Second problem is you only have forwarding from guest => wan, which doesn't exist.

Comment: They're getting IPs from the 192.168.3.0 net. I'll look into the the other things and update the OP.

Comment: Removed guest interface from stabridge. Added a screenshot for the firewall settings. "wan" is default, also for the other interfaces. Took this setting from [here](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/guest-wlan-webinterface#configure_the_firewall)

Comment: Those settings are not applicable because you are not configuring the guest network on the primary router. Therefore your current configuration is invalid and cannot work. Any change in ability to ping the 192.168.3.1 now that the guest network has been reconfigured? Also, I hate stabridge - any reason why you are using it? What is your main router?

Comment: Yeah, thatswhy I asked for masquerading or NATing or firewall rules to make this work. Removed guest net from bridge, still can't ping. I used stabridge because it's the easiest method to connect to my main router wirelessly and also allows to use the same SSID and therefore enable roaming (for the private net).

Comment: What is your main router? Can you not use WDS at all? (and are you sure you saved and restarted between your tests/config changes?) Also, can you ping the client from the route (the guest one, not the main one)

Comment: Main router is a FritzBox, I can not use WDS. These boxes use a proprietary WDS. Yes I restarted several times. The WRT is generally kind of sluggish when using Luci, I get a lot of "Connection aborted" and "Bad Gateway" messages, kernel and system log look fine for me. Good idea to ping from the router, I can not test this atm because I don't have a second client but will do this soon.

Comment: Well, the Fritzbox is also capable to configure a guest net. This is turned off for now because all guest are mainly on the WRT site. If nothing helps at all I'll buy a cheapo TP-Link, flash it with OpenWRT, turn guest net on Fritzbox on and relay the guest net with the cheapo device. I'll then have two device who relay the wi-fi but who cares...

Comment: Hmm. As it is everything should work, but lots of connection aborted and bad gateway messages suggest a different problem, either a flakey router or your connection isn't going the way it's supposed to

Answer (score 2):

Pinging 192.168.3.1 indeed should work.  So I think you should focus on this first.  I think the problem is in

```
config interface 'stabridge'
    ...
    list network 'guest'
```

since guest shouldn't be in the bridge (if it's in the bridge it's own IP will probably be ignored).

Comment: Removed the guest net from bridge, still can't ping. Added another screenshot in OP. The thing that drives me nuts: the exact same thing happened when I configured this with DD-WRT (Client Bridge Mode and added another virtual interface).

Comment: What happens if you keep your guest network but take down the stabridge?  Can you ping 193.168.3.1 in that case?

Comment: Mhhh, I can not stop it from Luci and what happens if I try from an SSH session you'll see in my latest edit. WTF?

Comment: I don't see any mention of what happens from an SSH session, but of course, if the SSH session is established via the bridge it might cause you some trouble.  Still, I think you should start by setting up each one of your networks separately (guest, wwan, lan), make sure they work, and then add bridging to it, piece by piece.

Comment: `ifdown` won't work on any interface. Working step-by-step is essentially what I did. Everything worked except the guest net. ;-) But you're right, I'll start over by reflashing this thing one more time (did this twice). If nothing helps I'll buy another device. Thanks for looking so far!